# show an alert box when the app is installed for the first time using shared preferences + flutter + dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, splash-screen

im developing an android app,

Where i want an alert box to pop up only when the user installs the app for the first time using shared preferences.

By default at starting the shared preference should be false and when the user installs the app and the alert box should appear, after that the shared preference should change to true.

When next time user opens the app, by the shared preference(true) it shouldn't show the alert box.

Only when the user uninstalls and installs the app, the alert box should appear.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool? firstTime = prefs.getBool('first_time');
  if (firstTime == null) {
    // show alert box
    prefs.setBool('first_time', true);
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: You are missing an `?` to be able to check for `null` :)

Comment: Everything is correct. It is not necessary to assign any value when it is opened for the first time. If null, the condition will be entered. ))

Comment: A `bool` cannot be `null`. Not in any modern version of Dart. You are missing a `?`.

Comment: the only thing missing in this code is "?" sign.

bool? firstTime = prefs.getBool('first_time');

I recommend trying to run the code. I'm sure you'll see it work flawlessly.

Comment: Yes? That is what I told you from the start.

Comment: Excuse me for not understanding. Good thing you said that. Thank you.